# Not able to understand behavior of pattern.findall() in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Being naive in Python, While learning re module in Python, I found something strange (I am not able to get it) :

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}')
list_phoneNumbers = pattern.findall('phone number : 123-456-7894, my home number : 789-456-1235')
print(list_phoneNumbers)

pattern = re.compile(r'bat(wo)?man')
batman_match = pattern.search('batman is there')
batwoman_match = pattern.search('batwoman is there')
bat_list_all = pattern.findall('batman is there but not batwoman')

print(batman_match.group())
print(batwoman_match.group())
print(bat_list_all)
```

Output :

```
['123-456-7894', '789-456-1235']
batman
batwoman
['', 'wo']
```

How come `print(bat_list_all)`, did not give list ['batman', 'batwoman']? What I am missing to understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you're using a group `(wo)?` so `findall` returns what matches this group:

- `''` for `batman`
- `'wo'` for `batwoman`

You may use a `non-matching group` : `pattern = re.compile(r'bat(?:wo)?man')`

---

> [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall): return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups**; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.

Comment: I thought (wo)? means, 0 or 1 occurrence of wo. Thanks for focusing on group.

Comment: @RaviJiyani It does, but the parenthesis also make a capturing-group, that can be retrieved, using findall for ex

Comment: Yes, just gone through documentation :

(?:...)
A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.