# Regex findall function is not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, findall

```
>>>sampregex = re.compile(r'Bat(wo)?man')
>>>batRegex.search(' Batman Batwoman')
<re.Match object; span=(1, 7), match='Batman'>
>>> m1 = sampregex.search('Batwoman and Batwoman')
>>> m1
<re.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='Batwoman'>
>>> m1 = sampregex.findall('Batman and Batwoman')
>>> m1
['', 'wo']
```

The findall function is detecting only the expression inside the parenthesis, I am not sure how to correct it, I tried using as follows but now it returned two separate groups:

```
>>> sampregex = re.compile(r'(Bat(wo)?man)')
>>> m1 = sampregex.findall('Batman and Batwoman')
>>> m1
[('Batman', ''), ('Batwoman', 'wo')]
```

Comment: This is NNth question with batwoman, where do you get it? Please inform the author of the resource to fix or explain this.

Comment: Automate the boring stuff with python

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60585794/not-able-to-understand-behavior-of-pattern-findall-in-python/60585858#60585858